# spring jdbctemplate method queryForRowSet throws table dosen't exist error for alias name

Tags: java, jdbctemplate

i am using spring jdbc 4.0.0 , Java 8

Imports:

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.rowset.SqlRowSet;
```

inside the dao method the following lines are executed.

```
String sqlStr = "select column1 , column2, column3 from (select a.column1 , a.column2, b.column3  from details a, info b where a.column1 =  b.column1) as e group by column1 ,column2, column3";

SqlRowSet detailsList = null;
detailsList= jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(sqlStr);
```

on execution i get the following error thrown because it recognize the alias name "e".
Note: This query is getting executed properly in command line.

```
nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'sampledb.e' doesn't exist
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:411)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:466)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(JdbcTemplate.java:521)
    at com.testing.sample.dao.sampleDAO.getDetails(sampleDAO.java:61)
    at com.testing.sample.controller.ServiceController.getDetails(ServiceController.java:336)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:748)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:833)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'sampledb.e' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3566)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2562)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2512)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1476)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Field.getCollation(Field.java:476)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetMetaData.isCaseSensitive(ResultSetMetaData.java:564)
    at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.initMetaData(CachedRowSetImpl.java:722)
    at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.populate(CachedRowSetImpl.java:639)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.createSqlRowSet(SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.extractData(SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.extractData(SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.java:46)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:455)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:400)
```

How to get this issue resolved ?

Comment: Exception says "MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'sampledb.e' doesn't exist", but query you provided doesn't mention 'sampledb.e'

Comment: What version do you use? There should be a second parameter SqlParameterSource?

Comment: MySQLSyntaxErrorException has thrown not by jdbc template but by mysql db itself. Check your query.

Comment: Why you don't use `JOIN` instead of this way ?